# Creating external tables from SQL Server using JDBC Drivers

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, hadoop, hive

I am trying to query Hive tables AND Kylin tables from SQL Server 2019. I was doing some research and found that MSSQL provide PolyBase as a form of interface to Hadoop storage. However, the examples mostly include creating tables and storing file formats into HDFS. All I need is to create an external table from MSSQL using JDBC drivers. Is this possible? I would like to avoid using ODBC drivers.

Comment: Create an external table where?

Comment: Create an external table in MSSQL to link tables in hive or kylin using JDBC drivers

Answer (score 1):

> All I need is to create an external table from MSSQL using JDBC drivers. Is this possible?

No.  The supported data sources are here:

- Hadoop
- Azure Blob Storage
- SQL Server
- Oracle
- Teradata
- MongoDB
- ODBC Generic Types

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/polybase/polybase-guide?view=sql-server-ver15